# print a file in landscape from Windows command line or powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I can happily print a file using `get-content` e.g. :

`get-content .\test.txt|out-printer "epson wp-4525 series"`

How can I do this in landscape?

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you in powershell but on the command line it is a matter of sending the correct escape code to your printer. Most printers support the HP escape sequences to do that. See eg [here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-bpl02705) for a basic list. You can either echo the characters directly to your printer, insert them in your text file or send them through separate files. In the last case you can insert the code

`Esc&l1O` in a file, eg landscape.prn, you will need also a code to eject the page from your printer `Esc&l0H`. The Esc is the Ascii 27 character, you will need to save this in an editor capable of this, in notepad you need to save the file as unicode.

Copying the whole thing to your printer goes like this for a shared USB or network printer

```
copy /b landscape.prn+text.txt+eject.prn \\pcname\shared_printer_name
```

or

```
copy /b landscape.prn+text.txt+eject.prn lpt1
```

if you use a parallel printer or redirect to lpt1

The /b is to copy in binary mode making sure all characters are passed.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I tried this but unfortunately the printers I am using don't seem to respond. I suspect these are "too clever" (Kyocera biz printers) - I am trying creating postscript files using cygwin enscript - encouraging results so far!